# How to change list to a list of points

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a list of angles `{a1, a2, .... , an}` and I would like to have a list of points `{{cos(a1),sin(a1)},{cos(a2),sin(a2)},....{cos(an),sin(an)}`.

I try to do it using `Map`, but I am beginner in Mathematica and can't make a proper code.

Comment: `{Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ {a1, a2, a3, an}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};    
Transpose[{Cos[lst], Sin[lst]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};

{Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ lst
(* {{Cos[a1], Sin[a1]}, {Cos[a2], Sin[a2]}, {Cos[a3], Sin[a3]}, 
    {Cos[a4], Sin[a4]}, {Cos[a5], Sin[a5]}} *)
```

Or

```
Through@{Cos, Sin}@# & /@ lst
(* same result *)
```